# How can I return a dictionary from a user defined function to a pyspark data frame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have defined the following function:

```py
def test_function(string):
    import nltk
    from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

    lower_string = string.lower()
    sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

    res_dict = sid.polarity_scores(lower_string)
    return res_dict
```

I transformed the function to a udf in order to pass it to a Pyspark data frame, by doing the following:

```py
udf_test_function = udf(lambda z: test_function(z), MapType(StringType(), DoubleType()))
```

I have a pyspark dataframe, comments, that only has a column, comment, that contains strings.

```
+--------------------+
|             comment|
+--------------------+
|                 nan|
|                 nan|
|                 nan|
|So far it has per...|
|I purchased it fo...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

And it has the schema:

```
root
 |-- comment: string (nullable = true)
```

I pass the udf to the data frame in the following way:

```py
test_result = comments.select('comment',udf_test_function('comment').alias('Result'))
```

The result of this operation should be the new data frame test_result, and it indeed has the type `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` and it should have two columns comment and Result. But when I try to show the results `test_result.show(5)` I get the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o161.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 10, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
```

This only happens when I use NLTK functions, as if I pass other functions to the data frame it works correctly.

I am using Jupyter notebook 4.4.0 with spark 2.4.0 running on python 3.7.2 (everything installed locally on my PC); I am under the impression that this is more a configuration problem than a logical problem.

But any help will be greatly appreciated as I am quite new to configuring Spark/Pyspark.

Comment: You have to make your `udf` robust to handle bad inputs. Add `if string is None: return None` to your `test_function`. (Or consider other error handling methods.) BTW `string` is a bad choice for a variable name because it conflicts with the `string` library.

Comment: @pault I will make the changes. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem it was a configuration problem as I was not sending NLTK library to the worker nodes of my Spark installation. 
I followed this tutorial and was able to solve my problem:
[NLTK in Spark tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/natural-language-processing-in-apache-spark-using-nltk-part-1-2-58c68824f660)

I also corrected the function to better handle errors:

```py
def vader_SID(input_string='Error'):
    import nltk
    from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

    sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

    try:
        lower_string = input_string.lower()
        res_dict = sid.polarity_scores(lower_string)  
        return res_dict

    except ValueError:
        print('Value Error!')

    except AttributeError:
        print('Atribute Error!')

    except TypeError:
        print('Type Error!')
```

The resulting data frame from the function is:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|             comment|              Result|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                 nan|[neg -> 0.0, pos ...|
|                 nan|[neg -> 0.0, pos ...|
|                 nan|[neg -> 0.0, pos ...|
|So far it has per...|[neg -> 0.0, pos ...|
|I purchased it fo...|[neg -> 0.0, pos ...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```